# Kill The [carreer] Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-blacklist

Really. We just cleaned up the [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag, and now we have a [carreer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carreer) tag?

Let's poke it with a stick. Or better yet, just kill the dang thing. It has [one question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145288/boring-vs-cool-ratio) and that question is closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what's worst, the tag, the other tags on the question, the question itself, or the fact that it has 2 reopen votes (really, people?).

I removed the tag from the question, it will die on its own. Unless of course someone brings it back, in which case we'll have to deal with it a bit more severely. As a rule of thumb, if a tag is so obviously wrong and it's on less than, let's say, 5 questions, go ahead and remove it.

Comment: The worst thing is his totally inappropriate usage of ratios "20:80"